# How to Center three Div's inside another Div

Tags: css, html

this has been trying my patience for about an hour so I thought I would ask.

I need to have three divs, centered inside another div that is inside another div lol.  Here is what the code I have looks like.

HTML

```
<div id="frontnav">
   <div id="front1" class="frontboxes">
      <h2>Gold</h2>
   </div>
   <div id="front2" class="frontboxes">
      <h2>Green</h2>
   </div>
   <div id="front3" class="frontboxes">
      <h2>Blue</h2>
   </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
/*  FRONT PAGE BOXES */

#frontnav {
    width: 90%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    height: 300px;
    transition: all 2s;
    -moz-transition: all 2s;
 /* Firefox 4 */
    -webkit-transition: all 2s;
 /* Safari and Chrome */
    -o-transition: all 2s;
 /* Opera */;
}

#front1 {
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
    height: 200px;
    width: 30%;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 19px #615D69;
}

#front2 {
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
    height: 200px;
    width: 30%;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 19px #615D69;
}

#front3 {
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
    height: 200px;
    width: 30%;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 19px #615D69;
}

.frontboxes {
    margin: 6px;
}
```

Comment: If you post an image that shows what you want, it will be easier to provide a valid answer.

Comment: I forgot to mention I am using wordpress and styling a page inside that . . All of these sugguestions are great, but they aren't working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

div element can only be center by setting margin css property as

```
margin: 0px auto;
```

Comment: do you mean center aligning all three divs mentioned on website in vertical way?

Comment: in this case you must use utility class e.g .split { clear:both; } within each div in order to remove floating, keep another div vertically align.

Comment: I mean horizontally centered ie  outter edge -> |__{div}{div}{div}__|<- outter edge

Comment: ok got it, float:left can't be align center, you need to find alternative way, even float:right, without float your goal is not achieved. only way to find parent div width and keep padding left, right in way to center all three divs.

Comment: i tested your code on http://jsfiddle.net/A6Jhh/3/, its looking centrally aligned all three divs.

Comment: I believe it is because the whole thing is in a page on wordpress, probably four other div's deep.  I ended up floating right, and adding 5% padding to the right hand side and it is very near centered.  I am going to leave it how it is, thanks for all your help.

view it at morrisentertainment.ca/wp  later!

Comment: How would you center the three divs inside a larger parent div? http://jsfiddle.net/A6Jhh/6/

Answer (score 0):

The `text-align:center;` declaration needs to be on the outermost div, i.e. `frontnav` in your example.

Comment: You might need to remove the `margin` declarations on that same div.

Comment: I have done so. . seems to make no difference. . . This is going to drive me batty, supposed to be a 10 minute job lol.  Thanks for the help!  Any other idea's?

Comment: Try eliminating the `float` and use a static position. Try getting one div to center, then perhaps put your three divs in that centered div and adjust the size as needed.

Comment: Yes, that has been the goal, I can acomplish with static sizes, however due to the media responsive nature I am trying to use % of width instead of set width.  Maybe I should just try to set it and then have different width's set for different screen sizes?

Answer (score 0):

Change the last rule to:

```
.frontboxes {
    margin: 6px auto;
}
```

and remove the  `float: left;`s.

Comment: That's what I thought.  However this ends me up with three div's that are stacked instead of side by side